# A song in XNA cuts off

Tags: c#, loops, xna, duration, background-music

My code:
Variables:

```
    //Menu Song
    Song mainMenuTheme;
    bool songstart = false;
```

LoadContent() method:

```
    //Load the song
    mainMenu = Content.Load<Song>("musics\\mainMenuTheme");
    MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
```

In the Update() method:

```
    //Start the song
    if (!songstart)
    {
    MediaPlayer.Play(mainMenuTheme);
    songstart = true;
    }
```

So the song is in .wma format, 6.32MB and the duration is 00:01:36. How to make the ***WHOLE*** song loop? Because when I start debugging it cuts off after a while and loops again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .mp3 instead of .wma for `Song` class.
Your code seems corrert.